# wordpress: mod_rewrite first "folder" name as a get parameter

Tags: apache, wordpress, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I set the wordpress permalink-structure to just use the `articlename` and got a .htaccess that looks like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

works fine.

but I want to distinguish between different locations (i.e. berlin, hamburg or muenchen) in my various template files. so I thought I'd add the location to the URL like this:

http://myurl.com/berlin/articlename

and now I need to rewrite this to

http://myurl.com/articlename?location=berlin

but

http://myurl.com/articlename

or

http://myurl.com/category/articlename

should still work. just look for predefined locations (berlin|hamburg|muenchen).

how do I need to adjust the RewriteRule above to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed this with the following additions to the `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !location
RewriteRule ^(muenchen|berlin)/$ /index.php?location=$1 [NC,QSA,P]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !location
RewriteRule ^(muenchen|berlin)/(.*)$ /$2?location=$1 [NC,QSA,P]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

So basically if what you're asking for is that `http://myurl.com/(word1)/(word2)/` (i.e. only matches ***exactly*** two words, no less no more) gets internally rewritten on the server side to `http://myurl.com/(word2)?location=(word1)` then here it is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule /([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$2?location=$1 [QSA,L]

    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: not exactly - only rewrite if `(word1)` is either berlin or hamburg - otherwise keep the URL as is.